# Get javascript Object attribute of attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JS Object that may look like one of the following:

```
// Example #1:
var data = {
    product: {
        value1: 'v1',
        value2: 2
    }
}
// Example #2:    
var data = {
    order: {
        value1: 1
    }
}
// Example #3:    
var data = {
    value1: 1
}
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
var inputName = 'product[value1]';
var data = {
    product: {
        value1: 'v1',
        value2: 2
    }
}
var value = something(data, inputName); // should return v1
```

inputName and data can change, I can have any of the above data Objects with an inputName like `'product[value2]'`, `'order[value1]'`, `'value1'`.

My guess is to use regex and get both attribute names. Is the a better way?

Comment: Are you unsure because of the changing keys (product, order) or because of the nested changing keys (value1, value2)

Comment: I'm searching for a solution that would let me get the value without breaking the inputName (e.g. I'm searching for product[value1] and would like to get it similar to data['value1'], but data['product[value1]'] woudn't work).

Comment: You can see your object as a tree with nodes and leaves. Start searching from the root, using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and if the value is an object, perform a recursion step. Otherwise, check the value if it matches your search.

Comment: What will be result of the search? *"The search in the last example is simple"* post the code for the simple example.

Comment: Providing some sample search queries with expected results would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I've added an example of what I'd like to achieve. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use underscore js _.each to iterate over the object like

```
_.each(data ,function(product){
    console.log(product.value);
});
```

see the link: http://underscorejs.org/#each

you can also use for each loop.

Also you can perform filter like below:

```
_.filter(data, function(product){
    return product.value;
 });
```

Comment: `_.each` is vanilla? If not specify what library you are using.

Comment: the library is underscore.js, just as @sumit chauhan explains.

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

If you want to give your function a string like `'product[value1]'` as argument you need to get all attribute values that you need to query for your result value. I did it with `query.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, ' ')split(' ')`. The returning array you need to check for empty strings and remove them. I did it with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
After that you can simply use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the returned array to get on each iteration the new value. In the last iteration you have your result.

## Code

```
function getDataValue(obj, query) {
    var attributes = getAttributeNames(query)
    return attributes.reduce(function(value, current) { 
        return value[current]
    }, obj)
}

function getAttributeNames(query) {
    return query.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, ' ')
        .split(' ')
        .filter(function(string) {
            return string.length > 0
        })
}
```

## Example

```js
var dataOne = {
    product: {
        value1: 'v1',
        value2: 2
    }
}

var dataTwo = {
    product: {
        subProduct: {
          value1: 'v2'
        }
    }
}

console.log(getDataValue(dataOne, 'product[value1]'))
console.log(getDataValue(dataTwo, 'product[subProduct][value1]'))


function getDataValue(obj, query) {
    var attributes = getAttributeNames(query)
    return attributes.reduce(function(value, current) { 
      return value[current]
    }, obj)
}

function getAttributeNames(query) {
    return query.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, ' ')
      .split(' ')
      .filter(function(string) {
        return string.length > 0
      })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you directly `query.split(/\[|\]/)` instead of introducing prone to error spaces ? Object keys can have spaces, and even be only spaces...

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to create a dictionary that directly caters to your search.

You can flatten your multi-level key value pair to create a dictionary that you can use readily. The below `flatten` function ([taken from here](https://gist.github.com/kirbysayshi/2ea881ebe643458311f4)) creates a dictionary like:

```
{
  "product.value1": "v1",
  "product.value2": 2
}
```

You can then just query it using `dictionary["product.value1"]`

This flatten function can be altered to format the keys like `product[value1]` if you wish so.

```js
var data = {
    product: {
        value1: 'v1',
        value2: 2
    }
}
var myDictionary = flatten(data);

console.log(myDictionary);
console.log(myDictionary["product.value1"]);
console.log(myDictionary["product.something else"]);


function flatten(obj, opt_out, opt_paths) {
  var out = opt_out || {};
  var paths = opt_paths || [];
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).reduce(function(out, key) {
    paths.push(key);
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      flatten(obj[key], out, paths);  
    } else {
      out[paths.join('.')] = obj[key];
    }
    paths.pop();
    return out;
  }, out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know possible attribute names, then I would define an array with possible attribute names, then iterate over them checking if there is a field with this name

```
const names = [
  'product',
  'order'
];

function findValue(data){
  if(data.value1) return data.value1;
  for(let name in names){
    if(data[name].value1) return data[name].value1;
  }
}
```